How to create Number of Order in MongoDB?
enter image description hereI have database of orders and need to create the No of Order when it appeares in MongoDB.
Is it possible? if yes, how to create, help, please...
Thank you so much for explanation.
Tries to search function in Aggregations, but can't find

Please see the following document for two ways to create an auto incrementing field. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

The record identifier cannot be a number, in MongoDB there are no "tables", it is just a list of many records, so the most efficient way to not break records is with hashes, as done by default.
You could add a new field "order_number", and modify it programmatically.
You should also evaluate whether to use MongoDB, perhaps your project would be better suited with a relational database, such as PostgreSQL, they have tables and a numeric primary identifier.
